# How to convert Matlab intrinsicToGeographic function to C++?

Tags: c++, matlab, gdal, geography

As you know, Matlab has intrinsicToGeographic and intrinsicToWorld functions to convert from intrinsic to geographic or world coordinates.

intrinsicToGeographic function get referencing object R, that create by georasterref function.

How can i find lat-long from pixel point, like whats is the lat long of pixel with X=3000 and Y=2000 in C++

Comment: You should tell us what you've tried, and what problems you ran into

Comment: with **georasterref** function in Matlab you could construct geographic raster reference object that has some options like 'LatitudeLimits' , 'LongitudeLimits' , 'RasterSize' ,etc
Now, i create a georasterref object with regards to this parameters, and then use **intrinsicToGeographic** function to convert pixel location(x,y) to geographic location(Lat, Long). So qusetion, How can i do this process in C++ with various libraries like GDAL or GeographibLib?

Comment: Gdal is a c/c++ library so use that directly. The key is to know what type of image file you have (i.e., geotiff, KML, RPC, etc.) and use the correct function in goal to read the file. I'm pretty sure this is what `georasterref` does, and it creates a camera model from the metadata in the image file from which image coordinates can then be mapped to geographic coordinates. Good luck.

Comment: @aichao Thanks a lot,. I dont understand `this is what georasterref does`. I have a TIFF image and want to create a GeoTIFF image. I use GDAL to read image with RasterIO function. i know that GDAL has SetGeoTransform function but i dont have TFW parameters. – AmiR Hossein 19 mins ago

Comment: If you just have a TIFF with no metadata (i.e., world file, KML, etc.) referencing the image, then you are out of luck.

Comment: I have log file of image and calculate lat0 and long0 of image. But i cant calculate pixels lat long. Did you know how to calculate TFW parameters from log file?